# Why java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException thrown when process list

Tags: java

By executing below code why i get the `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`

Here is Code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("One","Two","Three","Four");

        Consumer<String> upperCaseConsumer = s -> strs.add(s.toUpperCase());
        Consumer<String> printConsumer = s -> System.out.println(s);

        strs.forEach(upperCaseConsumer);
        strs.forEach(printConsumer);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Arrays.asList("One","Two","Three","Four")` returns a constant size `List` backed by an array, so you can't add elements to it.

Use

```
List<String> strs = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("One","Two","Three","Four"));
```

instead.

Comment: By Executing List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("One","Two","Three","Four"); 
  System.out.println(strs.getClass().getSimpleName());
it gives me class name ArrayList 

And

By executing 

List<String> strs = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("One","Two","Three","Four")); 
  
System.out.println(strs.getClass().getSimpleName());
  
it also give me ArrayList so how it makes difference whether i create arraylist by asList or using new ?

Comment: @RBS It's not the same ArrayList. The former is `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList` and the latter is `java.util.ArrayList`

Comment: Thanks, i need to read more in details for it.